# How to generate 0xE8 (call) opcode with C++

Tags: code-injection, dll-injection

Basically, what I have is a game which has a function `MyFunc()`, and it's called on 4 places in the game. One of the addresses is `0x10002000`, and the bytes are `E8 0B 83 01 00`.

I'm injecting a DLL, and want to patch that `0xE8` (call) to my own address. When I do it with Cheat Engine's Auto Assembler and write `call MYADDRESS`, it generates the proper opcode, and proper bytes.

However, if I do it with the DLL, this is what I get:
[image: Cheat Engine]

What I want to achieve is `call 74C611CC`. So I need to *generate* the bytes for the opcode to be like I want instead of what is it currently (in the screenshot)

I use this kind of code:

```
*(BYTE*) dwPatchAddr = 0xE8;
*(DWORD*) (dwPatchAddr + 1) = (DWORD) myFunc;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `e8` instruction is a *relative* call instruction, not absolute.  So the next 4 bytes need to be the difference between the pc when processing this instruction and your target function.  So what you want is:

```
*(BYTE *)dwPatchAddr = 0xE8;
*(DWORD *)(dwPatchAddr + 1) = (DWORD)((char *)myFunc - (char *)(dwPatchAddr + 5));
```

Note that the PC address used to compute the offset is actually the address of the *next* instruction after the call (what will also be pushed as the return address).

Comment: Flawless! Worked on the first try. However, I'd like to ask: why `(char*)myFunc` instead of `(DWORD)myFunc`?

Comment: `(DWORD)` would work just as well for 32-bit code.  `(char *)` can be used for either 32-bit or 64-bit.

Comment: Thanks. I searched, and found http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_26.html , which seems to be a reliable souce. `Call near, relative, displacement relative to next instruction`